# whats the difference between these two value function definisions?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, probability

I've seen in literature two different yet similar approaches when writing the value function in an MDP:

1. $V_\pi(s)=\sum\limits_{a\in A}\pi(a|s)\sum\limits_{s'\in S}\sum\limits_{r\in R} Pr[s',r|s,a][r+\gamma V_\pi(s')]$
2. $V_\pi(s)=\sum\limits_{a\in A}\pi(a|s)\sum\limits_{s'\in S} Pr[s'|s,a][r(s,a,s')+\gamma V_\pi(s')]$

Are those equivalent? what is the meaning of adding the sum over $r$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the same one. I believe the Sutton's first version of the book had the first equation. The second version uses the second equation which carries the same meaning but simpler in writing. The reward will be a function of s, a and s'. For a fixed a, s there is exactly one reward corresponding to each s' possible. So the inner summation over r can be removed.